# Retrieving user ID from Wordpress and using it outside of WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How can I retrieve the ID of a user that is currently logged in on WordPress, so I can use that ID in my own non-WordPress web application?

Comment: Please clarify/explain in further detail. Are you building a headless CMS? Also, please show an example of the code you have written so far so we can answer in better detail.

Comment: @JayDev95 I want information retrieved from the Wordpress API to be rendered on a page, there is no code i want to know if it is possible.